# Examples of conflicts with hyperref loading order

Tags: hyperref

I know that `hyperref` has to be last package loaded, with [some exceptions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/140456). I have seen many documents in which `hyperref` is loaded first and work as expected. So I'm looking for examples of documents loading `hyperref` before other packages and get an undesired result

Comment: well over the years this is getting better (and work's ongoing currently to improve things further) but if you look in the sources of hyperref (especially older versions) it patched many commands from many packages so had to be loaded after the package. But over time those packages get updated to be aware of hyperref requirements and don't need patching, also as more memory is avalable now hyperref delays many of its tests to \AtBeginDocument so that it can catch packages that are loaded later

Comment: Thanks for the insight, so over the years it will be more difficult to find those examples. Nice!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle your comment (as I understand) suggest that we won’t be able to find such examples. If I’m correct, I accept that as an answer

Comment: there are some left still I may construct something later of noone else does

Comment: Thanks for taking the time